# JSON stringify helper

Tags: json, dust.js

Considering the following context:

```
{
  dogs: [ {name: "rex"}, {name: "tobi"} ]
}
```

How can I dump dogs as an array, ie: something similar to `JSON.stringify(dogs)`

I tried with `{#dogs}{@contextDump}{/dogs}`, but (logically) it outputs:

```
 {"name": "rex"}{"name": "tobi"}
```

rather than:

```
["name": "rex"}, {"name": "tobi"}]
```

Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is possible using [filters](http://www.dustjs.com/guides/using-filters/). Your template would look like this:

```
{dogs|js|s}
```

`js` is basically JSON.stringify, and `s` unescape everything, which will unescape the quotes in the JSON.

See this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hNfup/1/).